# Why does PoCo HTTP server consume CPU on complete idle

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I've experimented with PoCo HTTP server and found it consumes some CPU even on complete idle. This is not high usage but if we have a lot of instances running it may become a problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For network services using poll it's normal to permanently use small amount of cpu time. Nginx and redis also have some cpu consumption on idle. To achieve zero cpu usage on idle you well have to use another approach to network communications.